# Rooting a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have a Galaxy Note 10.1 (GT-N8013EAYXAR).

I have tried literally everything, and I am at a loss. I have tried SuperOneClick which didn't even come CLOSE to working. I tried using Odin which seemed promising, so I went with it and kept trying. I tried stuff that was downloaded. I tried converting the official CWM to a tar.md5 (this made Odin crash). I tried adb methods (maybe I'm doing something wrong).

All I ever get is the factory recovery. I can't run Titanium Backup (or really any other decent apps) without su.

Please help. I'm at a loss here.

**EDIT -- SOLUTION**

If you have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, and are looking to root, here are some useful links.

[This is the post](http://rootgalaxynote.com/galaxy-note-10-1-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-10-1/) where I found the link to the superuser file that is to be flashed via Odin. The post describes the process. NOTE: *You do not need to flash CWM to get root.*

Here is the link to the actual [su file](http://stockroms.net/file/GalaxyNote10.1/rooted/Europe/N8000XXALGA_N8000OXXALG5_PHE_RootGalaxyNote.zip) that has been prepared for use with the Odin utility.

Hope this helps anyone that gets caught up in the process of rooting their Note 10.1. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this guide](http://rootgalaxynote.com/galaxy-note-10-1-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-10-1/) from RootGalaxyNote?

*This answer is pending an edit. Site is currently blocked at my location.*

Comment: i didnt use the link this guide suggested, but the page led me in the right direction. i DLed a su binary that i then flashed and now have su! thanks for the link =)

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen Could you provide the link to the file, so that it would benefit other people in future?

Comment: gonna put links in the original post... see the edit section =)

Answer (score 0):

You can read [here](http://www.9android.net/root-galaxy-note-10/). I think it's useful for you.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, if the link changes the answer is useless. At least, paraphrase the solution into the answer so that the answer is helpful even without the link.